# React native drawer always open in iOS

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-ios

I am using [react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) to create an `iOS` and `Android` app.

I have used [react-native-drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer) for my navigation drawer. This works fine in both `iOS` and `Android`.

I am trying to get a view pager in the navigation drawer so that I can swipe left/right within the navigation drawer similar to the [Slack](https://slack.com/) mobile app.

[image: Slack's navigation drawer with view pager]

Here is my implementation.

**Main.js**

```
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      drawerType: 'overlay',
      openDrawerOffset: .15,
      closedDrawerOffset:0,
      panOpenMask: .4,
      panCloseMask: .4,
      relativeDrag: false,
      tweenEasing: 'linear',
      disabled: false,
      tweenHandlerPreset: null,
      acceptDoubleTap: false,
      acceptTap: false,
      acceptPan: true,
      tapToClose: false,
      negotiatePan: false,
      rightSide: false,
    };
 }

...

<Drawer
    ref={c => this.drawer = c}
    type={this.state.drawerType}
    animation={this.state.animation}
    openDrawerOffset={this.state.openDrawerOffset}
    closedDrawerOffset={this.state.closedDrawerOffset}
    panOpenMask={this.state.panOpenMask}
    panCloseMask={this.state.panCloseMask}
    relativeDrag={this.state.relativeDrag}
    panThreshold={this.state.panThreshold}
    content={ <NavigationDrawer/> }
    disabled={this.state.disabled}
    tweenDuration={this.state.tweenDuration}
    tweenEasing={this.state.tweenEasing}
    acceptDoubleTap={this.state.acceptDoubleTap}
    acceptTap={this.state.acceptTap}
    acceptPan={this.state.acceptPan}
    tapToClose={this.state.tapToClose}
    negotiatePan={this.state.negotiatePan}
    changeVal={this.state.changeVal}
    side={this.state.rightSide ? 'right' : 'left'}
    >

    <MainContainer/>

</Drawer>
```

**NavigationDrawer.js**

```
render() {

    let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

    return (
      <View style={styles.controlPanel}>
      <IndicatorViewPager style={ {height: height} } removeClippedSubviews={false} indicator={this._renderDotIndicator()}>
          <View style = {{backgroundColor : 'green'}}></View>
          <View style = {{backgroundColor : 'red'}}></View>
      </IndicatorViewPager>
      </View>
    );
 }
```

In the Android app, it works as expected. But in the iOS app, the navigation drawer is always open by default.

[image: Screenshot of the iOS app]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did u found a solution?